# Wiki Row Counter For Wiki Table

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I have a pretty extensive table I have built out within my Wiki with the below formatting in terms of column structure. Is it possible to insert a counter within the Wiki that will track the number of columns in this table?

```
 |-
 | 1||[Site Link]||Country 1||Website Type||Location||Location Description||Start Date||14||Test||2.93%||1,126||1,126||
 |-
 | 2||[Site Link]||Country 2||Website Type||Location||Location Description||Start Date||16||Test||67.93%||1,226||1,113||
 |-
```

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, but there are a number of extensions that can do that for you, e.g.:

- <s>[Extension:Autoincrement](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Autoincrement)</s> (no longer maintained)
- [Extension:Variables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Variables)

With **Extension:Autoincrement** you can simply insert the parser function `{{AUTOINCREMENT}}` where you want that number.

**Extension:Variables** will give you more flexibility. With variables you would do something like this: `{{#vardefineecho:n|{{#expr:{{#var:n}}+1}}}}`

For even more flexibility, consider using **[Extension:Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto)** to enable a proper scripting language.